# How to use threadLocal for TestNG java.util.concurrent.Ex

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng, java.util.concurrent

When i run my test cases with cucumber textNg on jenkins with maven not always bu sometimes it give it error java.util.concurrent.Ex. I need to use synchronized for my methods to work properly.
I have maps and i have to use ThreadLocal but i am not sure how can i use it. Can you help me?

```
private static Map<Integer, WebDriver> webDriverMap = new HashMap<Integer, WebDriver>();
    private static Map<Integer, String> browserMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    private static Map<Integer, String> scenarioNameMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    private static Map<Integer, String> featureNameMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    private static Map<Integer, String> tagNameMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    public static Map<String, String> scenarioSteps = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public String getBrowser () {
        
        return browserMap.get((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
    public static WebDriver getDriver() {

        return (WebDriver) webDriverMap.get((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

    public static synchronized void startDriver(String browser, String scenarioName) throws Throwable {
        
        webDriverMap.put((int)Thread.currentThread().getId(), initializeDriver(browser, scenarioName));
    }
    
    public static synchronized void setScenarioName(String scenarioName) throws Throwable {
        
        scenarioNameMap.put((int)Thread.currentThread().getId(), scenarioName);
    }
    
    public static synchronized String getScenarioName() throws Throwable {
        
        return scenarioNameMap.get((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
    
    public static synchronized void setFeatureName(String featureName) throws Throwable {
        
        featureNameMap.put((int)Thread.currentThread().getId(), featureName);
    }
    
    public static synchronized String getFeatureName() throws Throwable {
        
        return featureNameMap.get((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
    
    public static synchronized void setTagName(String tagName) throws Throwable {
        
        tagNameMap.put((int)Thread.currentThread().getId(), tagName);
    }
    
    public static synchronized String getTagName() throws Throwable {
        
        return tagNameMap.get((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
    
    public static synchronized void setScenarioSteps(String scenario, String steps) throws Throwable {

        scenarioSteps.put(scenario, steps);
    }
    
    public static synchronized String getScenarioSteps(String scenario) throws Throwable {
        
        return scenarioSteps.get(scenario);
    }
    
    public static synchronized void removeFinishedMap() {
        
        webDriverMap.remove((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
        scenarioNameMap.remove((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
        browserMap.remove((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
        featureNameMap.remove((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
        tagNameMap.remove((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
    
public static void stopDriver() {
         getDriver().quit();
         webDriverMap.remove((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
```

`Thread.currentThread().getId()` i thing i have to change this one.

```
public String getBrowser () {
public static WebDriver getDriver() {
public static void stopDriver() {
```

i added synchronized for this methods but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try using ConcurrentHashMap. Also please add the exception and the full stack trace to your question.

Comment: You need to use ThreadLocal  driver instead of using maps. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/62674338/5324105

Answer (score 0):

Please use existing TestNG parallel execution process - xml config because if we separately do thread processing, it will lead us to dead-locking and we need to spend lot of time to make it stable. I strongly request you to use TestNG's parallel processing

> parallel="methods" / "classess" / "suite"

```
 <test name="Object's Operations" parallel="methods" thread-count="4"> <!--// parallel="methods" thread-count="3"-->
    <classes>
        <class name="Pages.Sensor.SauceParallel"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```